# How to send mail using go daddy in framework 1.1 asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sendmail

I have to send a mail from go daddy in a project, and that project is built in .net framework 1.1. I have tried the following link from go daddy support but there is no mail in my inbox.
[Send Mail from Go daddy http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1073/using-cdosys-to-send-email-from-your-windows-hosting-account please help me.

Comment: Some errors? Maybe it is in spambox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you headers showing the email is from a aol, gmail, yahoo, hotmail, live, aim, or msn email account?  Is so the email will not send as our servers will not relay email with headers showing from addresses of aol, gmail, yahoo, hotmail, live, aim, or msn.

Comment: Actually the mail delivered too late so that was the problem. I came to knew today when i see my inbox and it was full by those test emails. If you want to help me then could you please let me know this problem(Late delivery) is coming.

Comment: With shared hosting some delays during peak email times is not uncommon.  If the issue continues I ask that you submit a trouble ticket with the headers of a delayed message so that we may review.